# snprintf copying 2D char array

Tags: c++, arduino, printf, c-strings

Trying to populate a 2D `char` array. This code should just work:

```
char FilenamesBuffer[3][64] = {{"test1"},{"test2"},{"test3"}};
char FilenamesBufferTest[3][64] = {{"unwritten1"},{"unwritten2"},{"unwritten3"}};

//print destination buffer before write
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
  {
      Serial.printf("%c", *((char*)FilenamesBufferTest+(i*64) + j));
  }
  Serial.println();
}
Serial.println();

//copying

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Serial.print("copying ");Serial.println(i);
    snprintf(*(FilenamesBufferTest+i*64), 64, "%s", *(FilenamesBuffer+i*64));
}
Serial.println();

//print destination buffer after write
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
  {
      Serial.printf("%c", *((char*)FilenamesBufferTest+(i*64) + j));
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Outputs:

```
unwritten1
unwritten2
unwritten3

copying 0
copying 1
copying 2

test1ten1
unwritten2
unwritten3
```

Looks like only the first row gets copied. I tried casting the `char` array addresses as `(char**)` which doesn't seem like it should make a difference. But it breaks the program.

```
snprintf(*((char**)FilenamesBufferTest+i*64), 64, "%s", *((char**)FilenamesBuffer+i*64));
```

Output:

```
unwritten1
unwritten2
unwritten3

copying 0
```

and then strangely

```
snprintf(((char*)FilenamesBufferTest+i*64), 64, "%s", ((char*)FilenamesBuffer+i*64));
```

works

Comment: @Ravi Arduino is not C

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing yourself by using pointer arithmetic to access arrays -- don't do it; use array accesses instead.

So when you do:

```
*(FilenamesBufferTest+i*64)
```

That's the same as `FilenamesBufferTest[i*64]` which is out-of-bounds when `i` is anything other than 0.  You want `FilenamesBufferTest[i]`, which would be:

```
*((char *)FilenamesBufferTest+i*64)
```

if you *really* want to do the explicit arithmetic, but that is much harder.